# Extend Kähler form to a point

Tags: complex-geometry, harmonic-functions, several-complex-variables

I'm thinking about extending a Kähler form on manifold $M-x_0$ to $M$. Here $M$ is a complex closed manifold, and I equip $M-x_0$  a natural induced complex structure.

Following is my way of thinking:

I work on local holomorphic charts around $x_0$, Now consider function
$f=\omega(X, JX)$ for any local holomorphic vector field $X$. If I can prove $\Delta f=0$, then,

1.If I can also control the speed that $f$ go to infinity, then I can remove the sigularity of $f$ at $x_0$.

2. by positivity of $f$ I can show $\omega$ is non degenerate.

But I don't know if $\Delta f=0$ is true or not, can anyone help me? If not, I wonder if there is any other approach to extend the Kähler form?

Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Hint: First work out the case when $X$ is a Riemann surface (actually, just the open unit disk $D$ and $x=0$). Do you really think that an arbitrary conformal Riemannian metric on $D-\{0\}$ will extend to  $D$?

Comment: @MoisheKohan Thanks！

Comment: @MoisheKohan Yes when consider Riemann surface case, for any conformal metric I can construct a new metric locally by multiple a function $\frac{1}{z}$, which will absolutely blow up at origin and the correspondent kahler form is automatically closed since the dimension is low, but I wonder if it is similar to Hartogs phenomenon, like we can extend it when dimension is lagre?

Comment: @MoisheKohan I think I'm now find this statement is definitely false because it's impossible to extend kahler form on $D^2n$ to $S^2n$ when n lagre by topological reason.

Comment: Think: The same example shows that you should not expect harmonicity of $f$ either. To work it out in higher dimensions, think of Kahler potentials...

Comment: I cannot understand your previous comment. Do you mean $D^{2n}$ and $S^{2n}$? Unless $n=1$ (omitting the contentious case of $n=3$), $S^{2n}$ is not a complex manifold.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks! I'm not assuming $M$ a complex manifold previously, so I think it's not a good question, maybe some assumptions about complex structure will make this question look more make sense.

Comment: @TedShifrin But even considering this more suitable question, I think there is maybe a "counterexample" by consider the kahler manifold: $S^1\times \mathbb{R} \times \mathb{C}$, and its one-point compactification $S^1\times S^3$, which is hopf surface, but I'm not sure that whether their complex structure coincide or not.